# No implicit reference conversion from 'List<QSO>' to 'List<List<QSO>>'

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to create a generic class that accepts only a `List<T>`

```
public class MyTables<T> where T : List<T>
{
   public MyTables(T list)
  {
  }
}
```

When trying to instantiate it the compiler complains

```
var mt = new MyTables<List<QSO>>(Log.QSOs);
// Log.QSOs is an object property defined as 
// public List<QSO> QSOs { get; set; }
```

This is the error:

```
Error   CS0311  The type 'List<QSO>' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' 
in the generic type or method 'MyTables<T>'. 
There is no implicit reference conversion from
'List<QSO>' to 'List<List<QSO>>'
```

Why is it expecting a '`List<List<QSO>>`' instead of simply '`List<QSO>`'?

Comment: Note this is similar to an earlier post I made but since that one got nowhere I want to try again and simplify it in hopes of revealing the problem we are facing thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic parameter is `T`, which you have constrained to `List<T>`. Whatever you provide as the generic parameter must be a list of itself, which is presumably not what you want!

Here is a type that satisfies your current constraint:

```
class MyTable : List<MyTable>
{ }
```

You probably instead want to define the class like this:

```
public class MyTables<T>
{
  public MyTables(List<T> list)
  {
  }
}
```